# Sharing gulp watch statements between targets

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

**Current Situation**

We have a set of gulp watch statements that we currently use to trigger rebuilds when src files change:

```
gulp.task("dev:watch", function() {
    // General App JS
    gulp.watch([
        path.resolve(config.paths.root, "src/app/**/*.js"),
        "!" + path.resolve(config.paths.root, "src/app/**/*test.js")
    ], [
        "scripts:app"
    ]);

    // Templates
    gulp.watch([
        path.resolve(config.paths.root, "src/app/**/*.html")
    ], [
        "scripts:templates"
    ]);

    // Stylesheets
    gulp.watch([
        path.resolve(config.paths.root, "src/app/**/*.less"),
        path.resolve(config.paths.root, "src/styles/*.less"),
        path.resolve(config.paths.root, "src/styles/**/*.less")
    ], [
        "stylesheets"
    ]);
})
```

**The Desire**

In our e2e tests, we'd like to watch those same files and initiate e2e test runs when src files change.

We'd like to keep the watch definitions centralized (just declaring the watched files once) but utilizing those watch definitions for several different targets (rebuilds, initiating e2e test runs, etc).

**Current Solution (that we'd like comments on)**

We've wrapped the watch definitions in javascript functions and moved them into a module.  But the solution doesn't seem very gulp-ish.  We were hoping others might comment and provide some guidance as to whether this is the best way to achieve this with gulp.

*Wrapping and Modularizing Watch Definitions:* `shared-watches.js`

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = function (gulp, config) {
    return {
        watchAppJs: function (gulpTargetsToRunAfterChange) {
            gulp.watch([
                path.resolve(config.paths.root, "src/app/**/*.js"),
                "!" + path.resolve(config.paths.root, "src/app/**/*test.js")
            ], gulpTargetsToRunAfterChange);
        },

        watchTemplates: function (gulpTargetsToRunAfterChange) {
            gulp.watch([
                path.resolve(config.paths.root, "src/app/**/*.html")
            ], gulpTargetsToRunAfterChange);
        },

        watchStylesheets: function (gulpTargetsToRunAfterChange) {
            gulp.watch([
                path.resolve(config.paths.root, "src/app/**/*.less"),
                path.resolve(config.paths.root, "src/styles/*.less"),
                path.resolve(config.paths.root, "src/styles/**/*.less")
            ], gulpTargetsToRunAfterChange);
        }    
};
```

*Utilizing Centralized Watch Functions*

```
var sharedWatches = require("./shared-watches.js")(gulp, config);
gulp.task("dev:watch", function() {
    sharedWatches.watchAppJs(["scripts:app"]);
    sharedWatches.watchTemplates(["scripts:templates"]);
    sharedWatches.watchStylesheets(["stylesheets"]);
});


var sharedWatches = require("./shared-watches.js")(gulp, config);
gulp.task("test:e2e:autorun", ['test:e2e:continueOnError'], function () {
    sharedWatches.watchAppJs(["scripts:app", "test:e2e:continueOnError"]);
    sharedWatches.watchTemplates(["scripts:templates", "test:e2e:continueOnError"]);
    sharedWatches.watchStylesheets(["stylesheets", "test:e2e:continueOnError"]);
});
```

**The Question**

Is this the right way to do this?

We have a suspicion that we should be using a stream-based approach, using the watch's change events to initiate the desired targets.  Would a stream-based approach be more gulp-ish?